# NSlookup command works in CMD but not batch

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I am trying to use the NSlookup command in a batch file.  If I type the command in CMD prompt it works properly: resolves and echos the IP.   If I use the same command in a batch script I get the error "The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe" and a whole lot of ^C's over and over.  What is wrong with my command?

In CMD I enter:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %i in ('nslookup %domain%^|find "Address"') do echo 
address=%i
```

and for batch command I am using:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%i in ('nslookup %domain%^|find "Address"') do echo 
address=%%i
```

Comment: White space counts. Put the entire thing on one line and it works.

Comment: I don't think there was a space in it to begin with, I think it was just a notepad word wrap.  I made sure that it was all on one line and I still get the same results.  Thank you for your quick response

Comment: Are you sure that `domain` is defined? When I don't define it the batch file simply hangs and does nothing, but otherwise it works just fine.

Comment: I am acutally not using a variable in my batch file, just to make sure that isn't the problem. I only changed it so as to protect information.  This is why I am perplexed, it seems so simple I can't figure out why it is fighting me.  I thought it may be security policies at my company but they said no.

Comment: Run it again and copy the resulting output to your question.

Comment: The output looks like ^^^CC^C^CCC^^^CCC^C^^C^^^C^CC^^CCC^CC^C^^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^CC^C^C etc and occasionally it says The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe ^C^CCC^C^C^C^C^C  and it freezes, if I hit a button it starts again and stops.  If i let it run it does a great job at crashing my computer!

Comment: I also checked that the output was set to ANSI when saving the file

Comment: Is there a different sytax I can use to achieve the same end result. IE Use NS lookup to resolve an ip address from a DNS and set it as a variable/echo the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I have been using the correct syntax, I randomly clicked on the same script file and it worked.  The only thing I have changed recently is specifying the absolute path for nslookup but that didn't even work at the time when I did it.  Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score -1):

This means that the pipe has been somehow closed. This could be a problem with using `find`.

Try using `findstr` instead of `find`.

Comment: I tried changing to findstr and I also get identical results.  Thank you for the reply though.